# alot of maths questions, too hard! stuck on these ones

Tags: algebra-precalculus

1. A plane is flying in a straight flight when its sensors detect a disturbance. 
   Instantaneously, they find themselves flying towards the point at which they first detected this disturbance but from the opposite direction.
   They have experienced a displacement phenomenon, the mathematical function: $s(t)= 3t+(\frac{10}{t-5}) +2$

$s$ = displacement in $1000$s km from the disturbance was detected.
$t$ = the time passed in mins.
We are now back on course but displaced in parallel by $2000$ kms

i)  After how many mins, does the plane return to the point at which its sensors first detected the disturbance?
ii) After how many mins does the effect of the disturbance overtake the plane?
iii)    When does the plane actually turn each time?
iv) What is the expression for the final course on which the plane is travelling ?
v)  They are now back on course but displaced in parallel by $2000$km.  What was the original course and why are they displaced by $2000$km?

Comment: You look like a new user here. As an experienced user, you are highly encouraged to start writing down your answers first. Stackexchange is not a place for people to do your homework for free.

Comment: Please learn how to use $\LaTeX$.

Comment: oh ok, i've got...

Comment: I don't know what to make of your $s(t)$.  It is just one coordinate, so presumably distance from somewhere, but where.  Then you wrote, in part (10/t-5), which would evaluate to $\frac{10}t-5$, but you probably meant $\frac {10}{t-5}$.  Without a comprehensible problem, it is hard to give a good answer.